# How to return a GUID in token from Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I want to generate a GUID from an Azure AD B2C custom policy every time the user logs in or signs up and return the same every time. I have seen in the Microsoft documentation that we can use a `ClaimTransformer` to generate a GUID, but I am not sure where to use the `ClaimTransformer`. Is it possible to add the GUID generation as an `OrchestrationStep`?
[NB: I'm new to AD B2C]

Comment: Is this like a session ID?

Comment: @juunas yes, I want this guid to handle session logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you just wouldn't use the object ID for the user as this GUID? If you need to know if this was an already established session you could use the claim `objectIdFromSession` - referenced in the [SSO docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso#defaultssosessionprovider)

I might be missing the context, but these are the elements you would need.

A new claim type to hold the GUID - [Claim type doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#claimtype)

```
<ClaimType Id="continuityGuid">
  <DisplayName>User's Continuity </DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <AdminHelpText>Continuity GUID for the user.</AdminHelpText>
  <UserHelpText>Continuity GUID for the user.</UserHelpText>
</ClaimType>
```

A claims transformation for creating the GUID - [Claims Transformation doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#createrandomstring)

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CP-CreateGuid" TransformationMethod="CreateRandomString">
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="randomGeneratorType" DataType="string" Value="GUID" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="continuityGuid" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

A technical profile to execute the claims transformation - [Claims transformation protocol provider doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile)

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="Initialise-NewGuid">
  <DisplayName>Create a new guid for the user</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
  </Metadata>    
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="continuityGuid" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CP-CreateGuid"/>
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Add the orchestration step... this will be up to you where is best to place it... perhaps just before the final step - [Orchestration steps doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userjourneys#orchestrationsteps)

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="Generate-NewGuid" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Initialise-NewGuid"/>
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Output the GUID in the relying party section - [Relying party doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/relyingparty#outputclaims)

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="continuityGuid" />
```

Comment: Actually I want this GUID(session_id) to handle different sessions of user. Like if a user change the password once I want to clear all other sessions of that particular user. Also I'm want to use the same ensure the same GUID in our database when authorizing each request on server.

Comment: If you're looking at it that way, there may well be a simpler solution for you.

Have a look at this sample: [Revoke SSO Sessions](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/revoke-sso-sessions)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I'll check that. Do you have the list of CSS classes for customizing the AD B2C HTML pages?